# Why is my javascript function returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a code that will display a users GPA to the screen accepting the class name, class hours, and class grade. I have tested many things, removed global variables, did my best to make sure I was not rewriting over variables, but I just can't seem to get it to return something other than `NaN`. I have tried the code `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = finalGPA;` to print out the result and did it with `parseInt` and `parseString` and still couldn't get it to work. I would like it to print the result of the GPA. I have already been helped and the code is now functioning. Here is the code I have written so far:

```js
function calculate(classesTable) {
 var table = document.getElementById(classesTable);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var classStack = [];
 var creditStack = [];
 var gradeStack = [];
 for(var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
  for(var c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
   if(c == 0) {
    classStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
   if(c == 1) {
    creditStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
   if(c == 2) {
    gradeStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
  } 
 }
 var finalGPA = 0;
 var totalCreditPoints = 0;
 var totalHours = 0;
 var letterGrade = " ";
 var tempHours = 0;
 var tempCreditPoints = 0;
 for(var z = 0; z < rowCount; z++) {
  letterGrade = gradeStack[z];
  if(letterGrade == "A") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 4;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   totalHours += creditStack[z];
  }
  if(letterGrade == "B") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 3;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   totalHours += creditStack[z];
  }
  if(letterGrade == "C") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 2;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   totalHours += creditStack[z];
  }
  if(letterGrade == "D") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 1;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   totalHours += creditStack[z];
  }
  if(letterGrade == "F" || letterGrade == "I") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 0;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   totalHours += creditStack[z];
  }
  if(letterGrade == "W") {
   tempHours = creditStack[z];
   tempCreditPoints = 0;
   totalCreditPoints += (tempHours * tempCreditPoints);
   creditStack[z];
  }
 }
 finalGPA = totalCreditPoints / totalHours;
 alert(finalGPA);
 return finalGPA;
}
```

```html
<table id='classesTable' class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Class Name" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Number of Hours" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Grade Recieved" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow('classesTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Remove Last Row" onclick="removeRow('classesTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate GPA" onclick="calculate('classesTable')" />

<hr />
```

Comment: I suggest using Google Chrome debugger and use break points.

Comment: well, i mean, `calculate('classesTable')`, calls calculate with 1 argument. calculate expects 6 arguments. The not specified arguments will be `undefined`. that seems... like an incorrect usage.

Comment: Adding to what @KevinB mentioned `rowCount` and `table` are undefined in calculate function and thus at the end when you do `alert(finalGPA);` it actulayy does `alert(0/0)` that's why you get NaN

Comment: I have changed up the parameters and initialized the undefined vars now, still getting NaN. I have updated the post with my current code after reading your inputs.

Comment: @BradleyNewman check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addRow(classesTable) {
 var table = document.getElementById(classesTable);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "text";
 element1.placeholder = "Class Name";
 element1.name = "txtbox[]";
 cell1.appendChild(element1);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var element2 = document.createElement("input");
 element2.type = "text";
 element2.placeholder = "Number of Hours";
 element2.name = "txtbox[]";
 cell2.appendChild(element2);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var element3 = document.createElement("input");
 element3.type = "text";
 element3.placeholder = "Grade Recieved";
 element3.name = "txtbox[]";
 cell3.appendChild(element3);
 rowCount++;
}
 
function removeRow(classesTable) {
 var table = document.getElementById(classesTable);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
 rowCount--;
}
 
function calculate(classesTable) {
 var table = document.getElementById(classesTable);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var classStack = [];
 var creditStack = [];
 var gradeStack = [];
 for(var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
  for(var c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
   if(c == 0) {
    classStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
   if(c == 1) {
    creditStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
   if(c == 2) {
    gradeStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value);
   }
  } 
 }
 
 var finalGPA = 0;
 var totalCreditPoints = 0;
 var totalHours = 0;
 var letterGrade = " ";
 for(var z = 0; z < rowCount; z++) {
  letterGrade = gradeStack.pop();
  if(letterGrade == "A") {
   totalCreditPoints += 4;
   totalHours += +creditStack.pop();
  }
  if(letterGrade == "B") {
   totalCreditPoints += 3;
   totalHours += +creditStack.pop();
  }
  if(letterGrade == "C") {
   totalCreditPoints += 2;
   totalHours += +creditStack.pop();
  }
  if(letterGrade == "D") {
   totalCreditPoints += 1;
   totalHours += +creditStack.pop();
  }
  if(letterGrade == "F" || letterGrade == "I") {
   totalCreditPoints += 0;
   totalHours += +creditStack.pop();
  }
  if(letterGrade == "W") {
   totalCreditPoints += 0;
   creditStack.pop();
  }
 }
 
 finalGPA = totalCreditPoints / totalHours;
 alert(finalGPA);
 return finalGPA;
}
```

```html
<table id='classesTable' class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Class Name" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Number of Hours" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Grade Recieved" name="txtbox[]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow('classesTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Remove Last Row" onclick="removeRow('classesTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate GPA" onclick="calculate('classesTable')" />

<hr />
```

P.S. I am just updating your code to calculate GPA. I am not adding any of the cheks to it. You should implement checks for your calculator

Comment: Thank you for helping me get it to print out a number. The number is incorrect but I should be able to do some tracing to figure out where the issue is happening.

Comment: You are missing `children[0].value` `in table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML`. innerHTML will give you HTML and not the value of input field. Rest everything is fine in your code. I just updated my answer according to your latest code :)

Comment: I have updated the code I posted with the code I fixed to get the calculation working in addition to what you told me. I am also running into an issue now where it calculate the GPA fine as 1 row, but as I add another row it begins to get way off what the value should be. Am I adding the rows in an incorrect way, or is it that I am pushing them into the array in an incorrect fashion? I was thinking I should change creditStack.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].children[0].value); but I am not sure to what.

Comment: Updated the answer you were missing + while adding credits. Since you were storing it in a variable so you need to add + sign to perform addition

Comment: ah! Thank you again. I didn't realize you could do that. I will do some research into that to learn more about it.

Comment: yw anytime. Glad I helped :)

Answer (score -2):

`innerHTML` Will always return a string value. You then attempt to add these values to numeric values, which will perform a string concatenation, ex:

```
var i = 0;
i += '1';
console.log(i);
```

The above will output 01 to the console. Now if you try and divide by the string `01` javascript will understand that you really want to divide by 1. However if any other characters were to be found in the `innerHTML` collected values, like white space character, you will get `NaN` because you are dividing by zero, example:

```
var i = 0;
i += ' 1';
var val = 1/i
console.log(val);
```

Make sure you are sanitizing and formatting your values before performing operations on them.